# How to create array for getelementbyid to div more than 2 id of images for perspective tranformation with matrix 3 d

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new and not very experienced with coding, but I have been trying many different ways of array as well as converting  getElementById('screen')`to class or array, so I can have more than 1 image when using``, but nothing seem to work.  I tried it with the below code, hopefully someone can shed light on what is wrong.  The original script is fine, but I cannot seem to add more than one image for the perspective transformation. I ve tried so many and I lost track but use all advises regarding id to class etc..  Thanks

here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/rjw57/A6Pgy/

```
var imgElement = document.getElementById('screen');
imgElement.style.display = 'none';

var screenImgElement = new Image();
screenImgElement.crossOrigin = '';
screenImgElement.onload = loadScreenTexture;
screenImgElement.src = imgElement.src;
```

Comment: FYI, `<input />` tags are self-closing, meaning you write them as `<input ... />` or `<input ...>`, but NOT `<input ...></input>`.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking.  Do you have a list of urls that you want to append to the page as images?

Comment: here is link for teh entire code http://jsfiddle.net/rjw57/A6Pgy/   it works fine but I dont know how to add another image into the screen id 
http://i.imgur.com/eFSch02.jpg,       
http://i.imgur.com/vsZypFu.png